# Can a Homunculus Servant speak?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, languages

[Homunculus Servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/homunculus-servant)'s stat block reads:

> **Languages** understands the languages you speak

It doesn't seem like it can actually talk *back*, though, because of the verb "understands" being used here - if a servant could talk, I might expect to read "*speaks* the languages you speak". But a DM could rule that "understanding a language" is sufficient to speak it.

As a counterexample, [Giant Owl](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-owl)'s Languages section specifically calls out that it *cannot* speak its understood languages (emphasis mine):

> **Languages** Giant Owl, understands Common, Elvish, and Sylvan *but can’t speak them*

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: "[Can the Balhannoth speak?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159713)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No.

The *Monster Manual* explains how the "Languages" section of a stat block works:

> The languages that a monster can speak are listed in alphabetical order. Sometimes a monster can understand a language but can’t speak it, and this is noted in its entry.

The languages a creature can speak are those listed first with no qualifiers. When this section of the stat block specifies that a creature can understand a language (with or without stating that it cannot speak it), it means that creature can only understand that language, not speak it.

Comment: I recommend adding the following to reinforce your answer: "A monster that lacks the ability to speak might still understand a language." - DMG page 279